# How to write method with dependent type in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand Aux pattern in Scala.

```
trait Lst extends Any {
  type Item
  def get(index: Int): Item
}

object Lst {
  type Aux[I] = Lst {type Item = I}
}
```

Also I have some classes that override `Item` to `Integer` or `String` or smth else:

```
final case class IntLst(size: Int) extends AnyVal with Lst {type Item = Int}
final case class StrLst(size: Int) extends AnyVal with Lst {type Item = Char}
```

I would like to write method that can create List from `IntLst` or `StrLst` instances. I write this:

```
def makeList(l: Lst): List[l.Item] = (0 until l.size map l.get).toList
```

But it does not compile: `Expected class or object definition`

So, how definition of `makeList` should look?

Full code:

```
import Lst.Aux

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

  }

  def makeList(l: Lst): List[l.Item] = {
    (0 until l.size map l.get).toList
  }

}

object Lst {
  type Aux[I] = Lst {type Item = I}
}

trait Lst extends Any {
  type Item

  def get(index: Int): Item
}

final case class StringLst(size: Integer) extends AnyVal with Lst {
  type Item = Char

  def get(index: Int) = ???

}
```

Comment: Where are you defining that method? At the top level of a file? That would result in the error you're getting. Wrap it in an object.

Comment: Please provide a complete example—it's not clear how you're getting this error and the code doesn't compile for apparently unrelated reasons.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon if I define it in Main object I get: `Error:(9, 35) method with dependent type (index: Int)l.Item cannot be converted to function value`

Comment: @danielleontiev You'll have to provide a full example for us to debug that. That sounds like an error not with the definition of `makeList`, but with how you're using it.

Comment: @TravisBrown added

Comment: Your code doesn't give either of those errors for me. It complains about how `Lst` doesn't have a `length` member.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon sorry it was `size` in my code, fixed it above

Comment: `Lst` doesn't have `size` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is around `get`. Try this instead:

```
def makeList(l: Lst): List[l.Item] = (0 until l.size).map(l.get(_)).toList
```