# Type EnvT can not be found

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers

I have the following code that does not compiled:

```
trait DbSetup[F[_]] {

  type EnvT[A] = OptionT[F, A]

  def system: EnvT[Env]

  def user: EnvT[String]

  def password: EnvT[String]

  def address: EnvT[String]

}

object DbSetup {

  def read[F[_]: Monad](s: DbSetup[F]): EnvT[Configuration] = ???

}
```

the compiler complains:

```
not found: type EnvT
[error]   def read[F[_]: Monad](s: DbSetup[F]): EnvT[Configuration] = ???
[error]                                         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

How to import the type `EnvT` into the `object` scope?

Comment: @user It's possible that `s` is the instance.

Comment: @user well, we can't be sure. OP didn't provide enough information. But that's an option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662424/scala-methods-in-trait-cant-use-methods-from-companion-object/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
def read[F[_]: Monad](s: DbSetup[F]): s.EnvT[Configuration] = ???
```

Comment: @zero_coding Google for "path-dependent type", "method dependent type" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879353/how-to-write-method-with-dependent-type-in-scala Have you looked at the link I gave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879353/how-to-write-method-with-dependent-type-in-scala ?

Comment: @zero_coding Every instance of `DbSetup` kinda has its own version of `EnvT`. By doing `s.EnvT`, you're accessing `s`'s specific copy of that type

Comment: @zero_coding Could you be more specific what confuses you?

Comment: @zero_coding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types

Comment: I was confused, how do you know that can be written `s.EnvT[Configuration]`

Comment: @zero_coding well, I couldn't know that it was specifically `s.EnvT`. It could be any `x.EnvT` for `x: DbSetup[F]`. For example for `val x = new DbSetup[F] { override ...}`. You could make `import x._` so that you could access `x.EnvT` as just `EnvT`. But there was already `x: DbSetup[F]` in the scope, namely `s`.